# Need algorithm (logic) for best sum combination from multi group list

Tags: php, algorithm, logic, sum, combinations

I have multi group of data like

Group1 2,3,5,10,15 
Group2 4,6,23,15,12 
Group3 23,34,12,1,5

i need best sum (example sum(g1+g2+g3)<=25) from those 3 group like

1st (g1) 5 + (g2) 15 + (g3) + 5 = 25 (best combination)

Now, for next set of combination, no need to use above values from each corresponding group

Group1 2,3,<del>5</del>,10,15 
Group2 4,6,23,<del>15</del>,12 
Group3 23,34,12,1,<del>5</del>

2nd (g1) 2 + (g2) 23 = 25 (best combination)

Group1 <del>2</del>,3,<del>5</del>,10,15
Group2 4,6,<del>23</del>,<del>15</del>,12
Group3 23,34,12,1,<del>5</del>

3rd (g1) 15 + (g2) 6 + (g3) + 1 = 22 (best combination)

I hope this might be bit complex . But i might get better solution for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is best? Largest sum that does not exceed the target?

Comment: Looks like a good task for dynamic programming...

Answer (score 4):

It is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) problem.

There is a reduction from [sub-set sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

**Subset Sum Problem**: given a multiset `S` and a a number `k`: return true if and only if there is a subset `S'` of `S`, which sums up to exactly `k`.

**Reduction:**

Given an instance of subset sum problem at the form of `(S,k)`, create an instance of this problem at the form `(G1,G2,...,Gn,k)` Where `Gi` is a singleton group with the element `i` from `S`, and `k` is the number we are seeking.

**Proof:**

**Subset sum -> This problem**: assume there is a subset `S'={si_1,si_2,...,si_m}` such that `si_1 + si_2 + ... + si_m = k`, then by choosing the one element from each group: `Gi_1, Gi_2, ... , Gi_m`, they sum up to k, since each `Gi` include only the element `si`.

**This problem -> Subset sum**: Same idea here, given there is a set of singleton groups that sums up to `k`, we can find out which elements in `S` we need to get the desired subset sum in `S`.

**Conclusion:**

This problem is NP-Hard, and there is no known polynomial solution for it. Since what you are seeking is the optimization problem for an NP-Hard problem, your optimization problem is also NP-Hard. Thus, your best shot to get an optimal solution will probably be an exponential solution, such as brute-force: just check out all possibilities, and return the best match.

**Note:**

- It seems from example 2 you do not need to chose an element from each
  group, but to chose at most one element from each group, if it is not
  the case - this problem is still NP-Hard, but the reduction will be a
  bit harder.
- all the links in my answers to wikipedia are here for future readers, since wikipedia is off-line today. If you are interested, you can search these terms on google and see the cached pages.

**EDIT:**  exponential solution example [pseudo code]:

Note it was not tested, but the idea behind it should work: just check all possibilities for the first group, and recursively `findBest()` with one group less, so at the end- you exhaust all possible solutions, and return the best out of them.

```
findBest(groups, k):
  if (k < 0): return infinity //stop condition 1
  if (group is empty) return k //stop condition 2
  group <- groups.getFirst()
  min <- infinity
  best <- []
  for each element in group:
     (solValue,minResult) <- findBest(groups-group, k - element) //recursively check for solution, with decreasing number of groups, and modify k
     if (solValue < min):
        min <- solValue
        best <- minResult
        best.append((group,element)) //append the element we added to the solution
  //it is also possible to take no element from this group:
  (solValue,minResult) <- findBest(groups-grou, k - element)
  if (solValue < min):
     min <- solValue
     best <- minResult
  return (minResult,solValue)
```

Comment: complexity of the brute force solution is `O(n^g)` where g=total no of groups, n=total no of elements in one group

Comment: @RajendranT: actually it is `O((n+1)^g)`. [we also check no element was chosen]. I cannot think of a better solution, but if one exists, then, with the same reduction I showed to this problem, we can solve subset sum better then `O(2^n`) [or in small o notation: `o(2^n)`]

Comment: Thanks Amit.
Can any one convert this above algorithm in php or c/c++

Answer (score 0):

Subset sum problem has a pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming approach. We can map it to this variation problem with complexity `O(S*N)` and `O(S)` space, where `S` is the maximum sum (25 in your example), and `N` is the total no of elements across all groups.

This complexity doesn't depend on total no of groups, hence better suited if `O(N^G)` brute force solution will not converge for high values of `G>=10`. But note that this algo will not work for `S>=biginteger`.

In short, the DP recursive solution is as follows:

```
Sol(grp_i, S) = True      if(grp_i==1 && grp_i dataset has element S) // base case
              = True      if(Sol(grp_i-1, S)==True OR
                             there exists element 'e' in grp_i dataset
                             such that Sol(grp_i-1, S-e)==True)
              = False     otherwise
```

Once we find out if dataset is solvable, we can backtrack the solution.

Python program below:

```
def bestsum(data, maxsum):
  res = [0]*(maxsum+1)
  res[0] = []  # base case
  for group in data:
    new_res = list(res) # copy res
    for ele in group:
      for i in range(maxsum-ele+1):
        if res[i] != 0:
          new_res[i+ele] = list(res[i])
          new_res[i+ele].append(ele)
    res = new_res
  for i in range(maxsum, 0, -1):
    if res[i] != 0:
      return res[i]
      break
  return []

print bestsum( [[2,3,5,10,15], [4,6,23,15,12], [23,34,12,1,5]], 25)
print bestsum( [[2,3,10,15],   [4,6,23,12],    [23,34,12,1]],   25)
print bestsum( [[3,10,15],     [4,6,12],       [23,34,12,1]],   25)
```

Output:

```
~$ python2 subsetsum.py
[5, 15, 5]
[2, 23]
[12, 12]
```